# How to programmatically find and follow forwarded types?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-5

I'm trying to understand how to find and follow Types that are marked for forwarding.

For example, System.IO doesn't contain 'File', it's forwarded to System.IO.FileSystem.

The reason is that I'm using the Razor engine to compile some custom templates, so I need to inject the assemblies as simply including System.IO results in the following:

`Unable to compile template: template.cshtml(46,9): error CS1069: The type name 'File' could not be found in the namespace 'System.IO'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.`

Loading the System.IO assembly, GetForwardedTypes() doesn't return 'File'. (it does return things like Stream, TextReader, etc)

The TypeForwardedToAttribute doesn't appear in the assembly.GetCustomAttributes().

I'm struggling to find anything relating to 'File' in the System.IO Assembly object.

So how do I programmatically understand that 'System.IO.File' forwards to 'System.IO.FileSystem'?

What do I do from here?

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("System.IO");
```

Comment: A type can be forwarded from different assemblies, and the namespace need not be related. `System.IO` never contained a definition for `File`, which is why it's not there (unlike `Stream`, which [did live in `System.IO` in .NET Core 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netcore-1.0)). In .NET Core the type has always lived in `System.IO.FileSystem`, but a forward may have been added somewhere else for compatibility with Framework (where the type lived in `mscorlib`).

Comment: TL;DR you should probably extend your search to all assemblies currently loaded in the project, since you can't know for sure where the forward lives. Even then it can of course happen you don't find the type at all if you haven't actually referenced any of the assemblies that are relevant. Simply using the namespace of the type as an assembly name is, in any case, not good enough.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Makes sense, but if the compiler understand the forward, as in the error message is stating System.IO is forwarding to System.IO.FileSystem, how is it possible to perform the same logic and bring in the right assembly?

Comment: It does not say `System.IO` is forwarding anything, it says the type `System.IO.File` (which happens to live in the `System.IO` *namespace*) is forwarded. It knows this to be the case because there is at least one assembly (which is not named in the message) that contains a forward. I don't know which assembly it is either; try all the ones in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`. (The compiler of course uses a slightly different list of assemblies referenced at compile time.)

Comment: So I guess thats the question, which assembly has that forward? I can't seem to find it!